# How to type less verbosely

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I was wondering if it's possible to type handleSubmit in a less verbose way. Maybe creating a new interface by putting the eventDefault. How would I do that?

```
  import {Project} from "../ProjectsPage/Project";

interface FormTypeProps {
    onCancel: () => void;
    onSave: (project: Project) => void;
}

export function ProjectForm({onCancel, onSave}: FormTypeProps) {
    const handleSubmit = (event: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        onSave(new Project({name: 'Update Project'}))
    }


    return (
        <form className="input-group vertical" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="name">Project Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter name"/>
            <label htmlFor="description">Project Description</label>
            <textarea name="description" placeholder="enter description"/>
            <label htmlFor="budget">Project Budget</label>
            <input type="number" name="budget" placeholder="enter budget"/>
            <label htmlFor="isActive">Active?</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="isActive"/>
            <div className="input-group">
                <button className="primary bordered medium">Save</button>
                <span/>
                <button type="button" className="bordered medium" onClick={onCancel}>
                    Cancel
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `React.FormEvent` as the type of the `event` parameter:

```typescript
import React, { FormEvent } from "react";

// ...

const handleSubmit = (event: FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
};
```

React has its own synthetic event types for the various events, which you use when setting up the handler the way you are, with an `onXyz` property on the element. (When setting up a handler via `addEventListener`, which is still sometimes necessary, it's important **not** to use React's synthetic event types, since you're not setting up a React event handler, you're setting up a DOM event handler. But with the way you're doing it, you want the synthetic type.)

You *could* type the function itself as a `FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>`:

```typescript
import React, { FormEvent } from "react";

// ...

const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
};
```

Note that both `FormEvent` and `FormEventHandler` are generic types, accepting a type argument for the type of element that `target` will be. The default is `Element`, which is often sufficient, but you could also supply `HTMLFormElement` (e.g., `FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>`) if you wanted to be more thorough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Taking advantage of the topic, could you tell me if this type method is lagged? I will update the post.

Comment: @Stlick - I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by "lagged."

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a type to either to the function itself or to the arguments of the function, which is the event.

---

`React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>`

This is the type for the function. If you use it like this:

```
handleSubmit: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = e => {
}
```

Then the type for the variable e will be inferred as React.FormEvent automatically. So you don't actually need to know the event type because you can apply a type to the function itself and get the correct type.

---

Or you can assign the type to the event argument e.

```
handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
}
```

Now the type for the handleSubmit property is inferred as `(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void.`

Comment: What would the syntax look like?

Comment: No, the `event` parameter is not a `FormEventHandler<T>`. And where did `T` come from?